# Ignore newline characters when performing a fulltext search in MS SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, newline

I have a table with a full text index on one of its columns. The text in this column can contain newline characters "\r\n", e.g.

```
line1\r\nline2
```

Currently I am using the following SQL to search

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE CONTAINS(TextValue, '"*line1*"')
```

which matches successfully. However, my users would like to be able to enter

```
"line1 line2"
```

as a search term which should also match successfully. In other words, I would like the search to ignore "\r" and "\n".

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM civ.MetadataFieldValues WHERE CONTAINS(REPLACE(REPLACE(TextValue, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ''), '"*line1 line2*"')
```

but this returns the error

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Is there a way to achieve this using CONTAINS?

Comment: shouldn't fulltext search ignore newlines, whitespace, and fillter words like "and, the, a, etc" by default?

Comment: Doesn't work that way.  I parses out words.

Comment: Is "line1 line2" being supplied to the query (presumed to be a proc) as an input paramter?

Comment: @EastOfJupiter Yes, "line1 line2" comes directly from the front-end as entered by the user, so it is the input parameter. It is not a proc though; I'm generating the SQL manually as part of an NHibernate ICriteria.

Comment: @Kritner It does indeed ignore whitespace in the input. If I add spaces between line1 and line2 in the input string then it still works. It doesn't seem to do the same for \n or \r though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CONTAINS makes use of a full-text index. For this reason, if you were to modify the content of the field with a function prior to searching then the advantage of the full-text index would be nullified.

It is possible to create a full-text index on a view. Therefore, I would recommend creating a view with a second field containing the exact same contents as the currently searched field except that you would replace any undesirable special characters with spaces or something else innocuous. You can then create a full-text index on the new field in the view and use CONTAINS on that field in the view.

Comment: Thank you. What you said about the advantage of the index being nullified if you modify the value before searching makes sense. This is probably why my SQL statement above doesn't work. I will consider the view option you suggested or perhaps even find another way to avoid the problem altogether.